# How to test get_success_url in CreateView in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to write a test for the get_success_url method in a CreateView, to make sure it redirects to the newly created page. But the response status code is 405 instead of 302 as I expected.

views.py

```
class BlogCreate(CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = [‘author’, 'title', ’post’]
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('blog:blog-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

class BlogList(ListView):
    model = Blog
    ordering = ["-created"]


class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
```

config/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.url', namespace='blog')),
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import BlogCreate, BlogList, BlogDetail, BlogEdit, BlogDelete


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit$', BlogEdit.as_view(), name='blog-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete$', BlogDelete.as_view(), name='blog-delete'),
    url(r'^new$', BlogCreate.as_view(), name='blog-create'),
    url(r'^$', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
]
```

tests.py

```
class BlogCreateTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='john', password='123')

    def test_create_success_url(self):
        post = {‘author’: self.user,
                'title': ‘new blog’,
                ‘article’: ‘text’,
                    }
        response = self.client.post('/blog/new/', post)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, 'blog/new-blog/‘)
```

Comment: show your urls.py file

Comment: after create,which url does you web browser go?

Comment: after create, it should go to "blog-detail" with the slug of the newly created object. It works in the browser already, but it doesn't work in my test.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do a `client.post()` in your tests?

Remove the trailing slash from `/blog/new/`

Comment: Only GET method is allowed for your view for some reason. Maybe you have used some decorators on your view to just allow GET method?
The error means POST method is not allowed on the particular view `BlogDetail`.

Comment: No, I didn't. I have updated my post to include views.py

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: Thanks. That helped. But now I get 200 instead of 302. And it didn't create any new entry in the db when I do self.assertEqual(Blog.objects.all().count(), 1)